# Sort items paginated - mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a problem that I'm having a hard time solving. I have a list of users:

```
const users = [
 { name: "Noah" },
 { name: "Vladimir" },
 { name: "Nicolas" },
 { name: "Joe" },
 { name: "Timothy" },
 { name: "Nicole" },
 { name: "Mica" },
 { name: "Barack" },
 { name: "Ji Qin" },
 { name: "Patrick" },
]
```

These users must be paginated to be displayed in a table. To paginate these users I am using "aggregate", something like:

```js
// User.Query, I am using GraphQL
function resolve(_, args) {
  // Get arguments
  const { skip, limit, sortBy } = args;
  
  // Paginate users
  const users = await Users.aggregate([
    $facet: {
      count: [{ $count: 'count' }],
      users: [{ $skip: skip }, { $limit: limit }, { $sort: sortBy }],
    },
    $project: {
      count: { $arrayElemAt: ["$count.count", 0] },
      users: "$items",
    },
  ])
  
  /* This return something like
    {
      count: the total users
      users: the users
    }
  */
  return users[0];
}

module.exports = resolve
```

Well the problem starts here:
In the table I am showing two users per page, when I define a "limit", for example 2, it brings me two users per page, the problem is when ordering the users. When I sort the users by ascending name, it should bring me something like:

```
const users = [
  { name: "Barack" },
  { name: "Ji Qin" },
  { name: "Joe" },
  { name: "Mica" },
  { name: "Nicolas" },
  { name: "Nicole },
  { name: "Noah" },
  { name: "Patrick" },
  { name: "Timothy" },
  { name: "Vladimir" },
]
```

But it is ordering only the two elements that it brings me: on page 1, Noah and Vladimir return, on page 2, Joe and Nicolas return, on page 3, Nicole and Timothy return. Should return the users like the example above. How to solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: If you understand aggregation executes pipeline stages in sequence whatever we specify, so what happens here is your sort operation executes only on 2 elements means after pagination, as per your sequence the `$sort` stage should be in the first position, put `$sort` stage before `$skip` stage.

Comment: can you show a example? It would be something like this: [{ $sort: sortBy }, { $skip: skip }, { $limit: limit }] ?

Comment: yes it is correct `[{ $sort: sortBy }, { $skip: skip }, { $limit: limit }]`.

Comment: make the change and check that it does not return properly, users sorted ascending

Comment: I just solved the problem, adding { $sort: sortBy } before facet, now it really sorts them right, thanks a lot!

Comment: I just have to clarify that if there are names that start in lowercase and others in uppercase, you will see an error, therefore the use of "collation" solves that problem